# inject model in laravel controllers constructor

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, coding-style

I want to know if this is a good practice to use my model class in controllers in this way :

```
public function __construct(Rule $rules)
{
    $this->rules = $rules;
}
```

I do not want to repeat myself in my controllers so I want to know what is the best approach for that

Comment: u can `use Rule;` before the controller class, ,may be i am wrong but thats how i usel

Comment: That's called Dependency Injection and is a good practice. To make it even better, your `Rule` class should implement an interface and then you can type hint the interface instead: `__construct(RuleInterface $rule)`. Then your controller will be more testable since you can pass a mock class instead as long as it implements the same interface.

Comment: @Jigs1212 - That doesn't really answer the question about dependency injection, though. `use` is simply used so you can access the class without writing the full namespace.

Comment: ...if someone is wondering, "interface" is the general term for what Laravel call "contract".

Comment: So did you get proper answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use Dependency Injection - it is very good practice.

According to documentation:
Dependency injection is a fancy phrase that essentially means this: class dependencies are "injected" into the class via the constructor or, in some cases, "setter" methods.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The user repository implementation.
     *
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  UserRepository  $users
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = $this->users->find($id);

        return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
    }
}
```

In this example, the UserController needs to retrieve users from a data source. So, we will inject a service that is able to retrieve users. In this context, our UserRepository most likely uses Eloquent to retrieve user information from the database. However, since the repository is injected, we are able to easily swap it out with another implementation. We are also able to easily "mock", or create a dummy implementation of the UserRepository when testing our application.

Read also about Service Container - it is powerful tool:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container

Comment: Is there any performance benefit from injecting it into constructor versus doing `app(UserRepository::class)`  in the show method?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice for injecting models in controllers, however, the recommended approach is:

- Have a use statement at the top of your controller file
- Implement it in the functions that requires access to the model, i would not recommend you do it in your controller
- If you have a look at the documentation, you will be able to bind the model directly to your route and eliminate some hassle of Model::find(id) https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

The constructor approach you presented is recommended in using other classes like repositories, singletons, or whatever functionality you wish to inject, see the docs for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container

Hope this helps